# Saving timestamp with GORM works with SQLite but not Postgres

Tags: postgresql, go-gorm

This is my model:

```
type Event struct {
SessionId string    `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;not null"`
Received  int64     `gorm:"type:timestamp;primary_key;not null"`
EventType EventType `gorm:"primary_key;not null"`
UserId    string    `gorm:"type:uuid"`
GameId    string
Story     string
}
```

If I use SQLite the "Received" timestamp is stored correctly as Unix timestamp. However, with Postgres driver I get:

```
 pq: date/time field value out of range: "1593187082040"
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `type:timestamp` takes time.Time and not int64. To solve the problem I had to change the field type to time.Time and also parse the timestamp. However, since the timestamp value is in "ms", parsing it in Go is a bit tricky:

```
time.Unix(0, 1593187082040*int64(time.Millisecond))
```